# How to sort an NSArray of keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` of keys from an `NSDictionary` like this:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[myDict allKeys]];
[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Why doesn't the array get ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its useful for you

```
NSDictionary *stateZip;
NSArray *states;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];         
self.stateZip=dictionary;
[dictionary release];


NSArray *component = [self.stateZip allKeys];
NSArray *sorted =[component sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
self.states=sorted;
```

ragards,
CNSivakUmar

Answer (score 0):

Heyy Try this....

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
```

so do I put this in the data.h/m file as the NSMutablearray is created with the data or in the viewcontroller.h/m file as I need to display the data in a table?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@”self” ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
[sortDesc release];
```

For More information, have a look at

1. NSSortDescriptor
2. Sorting-NSArrays

Comment: does not work...
[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a58bc0